# Spring Security - Login page not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Im trying to create authentication using JWT Token using Spring Security. Im trying to make small changes in config but when I do that I cant run /login page because there is 404 not found error. I have class `SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and 2 methods:

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withUser("test")
                .password("{bcrypt}" + new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("test"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
}
```

I have overrided configure methods and added `permitAll()` to `.formLogin()` but when Im trying to open http://localhost:8080/login I got 404 not found error. What I did wrong? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The permission order is important,

try following

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
}
```

Comment: If im trying to call .formLogin before anyRequest I got error `cannot find symbol method formLogin()`. Looks like anyRequest should be called before formLogin()

Comment: try ``` .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/ping**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();```

Comment: Got error `Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest`. If I removed that antMatcher app is starting but /login endpoint is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Since you have customized the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` by doing `authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))`, Spring Security will not generate the login page for you, because it understands that you are not using the defaults. If you remove the customization of the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` the login page should be available.

There are more details in the `DefaultLoginPageConfigurer`, but it looks like this:

```java
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void configure(H http) {
    AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint = null;
    ExceptionHandlingConfigurer<?> exceptionConf = http.getConfigurer(ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.class);
    if (exceptionConf != null) {
        authenticationEntryPoint = exceptionConf.getAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }
    if (this.loginPageGeneratingFilter.isEnabled() && authenticationEntryPoint == null) {
        this.loginPageGeneratingFilter = postProcess(this.loginPageGeneratingFilter);
        http.addFilter(this.loginPageGeneratingFilter);
        LogoutConfigurer<H> logoutConfigurer = http.getConfigurer(LogoutConfigurer.class);
        if (logoutConfigurer != null) {
            http.addFilter(this.logoutPageGeneratingFilter);
        }
    }
}
```